# Writing a proper regex to remove everything between certain strings for find and replace in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have many lines of Dialogue that look like below:

```
     671 +++$+++ "murderland" +++$+++ 672 +++$+++ saundra +++$+++  +++$+++ What are you DOING here ?
     672 +++$+++ "murderland" +++$+++ 673 +++$+++ bruce +++$+++ 671 +++$+++ I work here, remember ?
```

I want them to be

```
     What are you DOING here ?
     I work here, remember ?
```

I have it in a .txt and I thought I should use notepad++ find and replace with a regex pattern.

Any idea how to format that regex?

Comment: what have you done so far to resolve this problem?

Comment: Next time try to include what have you tried by yourself to solve the question. Otherwise your question may be downvoted. See here: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find what: `^.+\+{3}\h+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- Check "Regular Expression"
- Uncheck ". matches newline"

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
.+      # 1 or more any character but newline
\+{3}   # 3 plus
\h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: this did exactly as needed thank you- removed 671 +++$+++ "murderland" +++$+++ 672 +++$+++ saundra +++$+++  +++$+++  before all the dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the find: `[^+$]*$`

The brackets means select all EXCEPT + or $, then select as many as possible until the end. Try that.

If that works then just find all matches and copy/paste

Comment: Nice try. However, since OP wants to remove the unwanted text, and OP is using a text editor, you would probably need to select the 'bad' part instead of the good 'part'. Your regexp may be OK for using in an scripting language. Anyways, bear in mind that your regexp would fail with a phrase like this `How much is 1 + 1?`

Answer (score 0):

Take the following expression

```
.+?(?!.*\++)\s+(.+)
```

And replace it with the first capture group (`$1` or `\1`), see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ppmko2/1/).